# When is this set convex and compact?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, lebesgue-measure

$ S= \{(f_1,f_2)\in  L^2(I)\times L^2(I)| f_1(x)+f_2(x)\leq 1, a.e.;   0\leq f_1(x)\leq a(x)\leq 1, a.e.; 0\leq f_2(x)\leq b(x)\leq 1, a.e. \}$

To make  $S$ to be convex and compact, does $a,b$ need to be continuous or only $a,b \in L^2(I)$   and compatible with above constraints is enough?

Comment: It seems that $S$ is always convex.

Comment: I hardly see whether this could be compact (the only way I see is taking $a=b=0$). Recall that if the interior of a closed set is not empty, then it cannot be compact.

Comment: I don't fully understand your point. So only in case of a=b=0, then it cannot be compact? Or as long as we have nonempty interior, it is compact?

Comment: In general in an infinite dimensional space, closed and bounded set are very likely to be noncompact.

Comment: Could I apply the following theorem if I define weak topolgy induced by L^2 norm? From wiki: A special case of the Banach–Alaoglu theorem is the sequential version of the theorem, which asserts that the closed unit ball of the dual space of a separable normed vector space is sequentially compact in the weak* topology.

Comment: Of course, but in that case it is compact in a different (weaker) topology, not in the usual $L^2$ (strong) topology. (You might need to check if $S$ is closed wrt this weak topology)

Comment: So the set can be weakly compact?

Comment: Assuming that $I$ is the unit interval, the set is always closed and convex, hence weakly closed. It is also bounded, so it is weakly compact. Whether it is compact in the norm topology is a different matter.